# Adding Paypal Express Checkout for multiple domains

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I'm working with a multi-site setup (via Domain Access) and am having issues using Paypal Express Checkout on more than one domain.

What I have done so far:

- Add a new Payment Method Rule with:

  - Event = Select available payment methods for an order
  - Rule = an existing component with a Domain Comparison element
  - Action = Enable Payment Method : Paypal Express Checkout
- Edited the Action element to add in the updated Paypal payment settings (user, pass, Signature)
- Ensure Rule is active

This does not add the Paypal Checkout button to `/cart` like I expected.

For testing, I edited the component for the domain that does have it and used the new domain for the Domain Comparison.  This *did* add the Paypal button to the second domain.  The only differences between these rules:

- The component used in the rule has a different domain
- The payment settings (user, pass, signature)
- The original one has a status of *Overridden* whereas the new one has *Custom*

I appreciate any suggestions for troubleshooting the issue - let me know if you need more information!

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is not currently in the Paypal EC module.  Please see https://www.drupal.org/node/2130605 for more information.

Basically, the rule that is created by enabling the Paypal EC module is hard coded into the .module file, making it impossible to use more than one instance without patching the module.